# Getting an error then trying to add a new mvc5 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-4.5

Then i tried to add an extra controller to an existing MVC5 solution. I have tried the normal way to add like so:

> Right-click -> Add -> Controller -> MVC5 Controller - Empty

. 
After selecting Add i get this error message!! Anybody who has seen this before. I have the newest update for VS2013 Premium. I have not been able to find anybody with the same issue. [image]

**Update:** I'm not able to add any type of MVC5 controllers.

**Update 2:** By suggestion i have run fuslogvw.exe and i gives me three errors.
[First exception](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2230967/Error/Devenv.exe.txt), [Second](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2230967/Error/Devenv.exe1.txt) and [Third](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2230967/Error/vstest.discov.txt)

Comment: are you able to add any of the other controller types? (The most common one being with views, using entity Framework)?

Comment: close down visual studio, start fuslogvw.exe and make sure its set to log bind failures (must be admin to change). Then start visual studio and try to add a controller again. Check fuslogvw.exe for more details on "what" is failing the load.

Comment: Hi @MarvinSmit i have tried like you suggested, and i can see that i gives me three errors. But i can't se why im getting thees error.

Comment: So, which asm is unable to be loaded according to the log? and is it missing or a version mismatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to the problem was to repair Visual Studio.